# Jquery Get array from json and see if value exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to write a script that retrieves data from JSON using jquery. I searched the downloaded array. How to find the value to perform any operation.
I pull out the data using getJSON and everything works. But I'm having trouble finding the search. Can anyone help me? This data from JSON:

```
[{"id":"10","data":"12345"},{"id":"11","data":"6666"}]
```

Comment: finding the search?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about, but [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) are a good source for how to traverse arrays of objects.

Comment: A simple `for()` loop should work. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to search through an array would be....

```
var data = [{"id":"10","data":"12345"},{"id":"11","data":"6666"}];

for(var row in data)
{
    var item = data[row]; //This is the object {id:..., data:...}

    if(item.id == ...) //Use if statement to search for data
    {
       //do something here when data is found
    }
}
```